# i am making Point of Sale and i want to get nettotal of the products, using ajax but i am having trouble in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

**this is my javascript**

```
<script>

function multiply(id) {

    var quantity = $("#quantity"+id).val();

    var price = $("#price"+id).text();



    var dataArray= 'quantity1='+ quantity + '&price1='+ price;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxmultiply.php",
        data: dataArray,
        type: 'POST',

        success: function (data) {
              $("#total"+id).(data);

        }

        });

}


</script>
```

I am able to get the total of the products but i am having issue in getting net total of the product, i am doing this using `ajax`, when i add the total it will give me previous value as concatenated with next value,i tried using through array but it also didn't work, now i store the total value in new table and then fetch it from there and add it but i didn't give me required answer, i tried to use array in it but it also didn't work for me

**This is my `ajaxmultiply.php` file code**

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';
   $quantity=$_POST['quantity1'];
   $price = $_POST['price1'];
   $total= $quantity * $price;

   //echo $total;
   $query =mysqli_query ($conn,"INSERT INTO grand_total (total) VALUES 
  ('$total')");

  $getdata=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM grand_total");
   while ($fetchdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
    $newtotal = $fetchdata['total'];
    $id = $fetchdata['id'];
  $grandTotal=$newtotal + $newtotal;

echo $grandTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop should be like below:

```
$grandTotal = 0;
while ($fetchdata=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
    $newtotal = $fetchdata['total'];
    $id = $fetchdata['id'];
  $grandTotal += $newtotal;

}

echo $grandTotal;
```